# Can subject complement occur after “as”

Tags: sentence, clauses, subjects

In the sentence : She first came to Canada on her own in 1998, and committed to music-her passion, both as a songwriter and a singer...”

Is “as [a songwriter]/ [a singer]” subject complement? I found the sentence as I was reading an article online and haven’t been able to stop thinking about the “as a singer....” part since. I’ve been trying to find the answer online but couldn’t find anything. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no linking verb in your sentence, so there is no subject complement.

*As* is a preposition here, and *as a songwriter and a singer* is a prepositional phrase. The prepositional phrase acts as an adverb to modify the verb (intransitive) *committed*.

You can simplify your sentence to better see this:

> *She committed to music as a songwriter and a singer.*

Comment: But this changes the sentence significantly. _Commit X to Y_ is very different from _commit to Y_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The OP's question is regarding _commit **to** X **as** Y_. No changes made on my part. _She committed **to** music **as** a songwriter and a singer_.

Comment: Ah. I'm reading it as 'She first came to Canada on her own in 1998, and committed to music: her passion, both as a songwriter and a singer.' (: meaning the following) Possibly the appositive reading 'She first came to Canada on her own in 1998, and committed to music (her passion), both as a songwriter and a singer...'  _Is_ the more likely. But the improper use of an ungapped hyphen renders the question in need of clarification.